# Como validar uma propriedade do tipo IEnumerable usando DataAnnotations?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Eu tenho um `IEnumerable<long> selectedItems` ele é para exibir um `select` para selecionar multiplos valores, eu quero validar esse `IEnumerable` usando o `DataAnnotations` para verificar se ele esta vazio pois ele precisa pelo menos ter um valor selecionado. Estou tentando usar o `Required` mas nao esta funcionando. Como posso fazer isso ?

Estou tentando assim.

**Model**

```
public class EmpresaModel{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Selecione ao menos uma forma de pagamento disponível")]
    public IEnumerable<long> selectedItems { get; set; }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="@Html.IdFor(model => model.selectedItems)" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Formas de pagamento disponíveis <img src="~/Imagens/required.png" height="6" width="6"></label>
    @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.selectedItems, Model.formasPagto, new { Class = "form-control", placeholder = "Selecione as formas de pagamento disponíveis", @multiple = true})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.formasPagto)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem um erro no HTML no `ValidationMessageFor` deveria ser assim:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.selectedItems)
```

e o valor que estava `formasPagto` era errado.

***Html completo:***

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Store", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="@Html.IdFor(model => model.selectedItems)" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Formas de pagamento disponíveis<img src= "~/Imagens/required.png" height= "6" width= "6" ></label>
        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.selectedItems, new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem() { Value = "1", Text = "1" }, new SelectListItem() { Value = "2", Text = "2" } }, new { Class = "form-control", placeholder = "Selecione as formas de pagamento disponíveis" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.selectedItems)
    </div>
    <button>Enviar</button>
}
```

a Validação que você colocou está correta é `Required` mesmo o que faltou acredito ser o `JQuery` e seus complementos para validação:

> `<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>`
>
> `<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>`
>
> `<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>`

Tem um arquivo que fica melhor de configurar isso na pasta `App_Start` no arquivo `BundleConfig`, faça uma alteração assim:

```
namespace WebApp
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js", 
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

ou seja, adicionando `"~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"` para fazer a primeira validação do lado do cliente.

Comment: precisou retirar o `@multiple = true` tbm no HTML. Mas agora funcionou blzinha. obrigado.

Comment: @FernandoPaiva eu utilizei com multiple e também foi certinho, mas, tudo bem o que importa que sua dúvida foi solucionada! e fiz a edição para ficar do jeito que foi a solução.